# Check if values in a set are in a numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if a NumPyArray has values in it that are in a set, and if so set that area in an array = 1. If not set a keepRaster = 2.

```
numpyArray = #some imported array
repeatSet= ([3, 5, 6, 8])

confusedRaster = numpyArray[numpy.where(numpyArray in repeatSet)]= 1
```

Yields:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Is there a way to loop through it?

```
 for numpyArray
      if numpyArray in repeatSet
           confusedRaster = 1
      else
           keepRaster = 2
```

To clarify and ask for a bit further help:

What I am trying to get at, and am currently doing, is putting a raster input into an array. I need to read values in the 2-d array and create another array based on those values. If the array value is in a set then the value will be 1. If it is not in a set then the value will be derived from another input, but I'll say 77 for now. This is what I'm currently using. My test input has about 1500 rows and 3500 columns. It always freezes at around row 350.

```
for rowd in range(0, width):
    for cold in range (0, height):
        if numpyarray.item(rowd,cold) in repeatSet:
            confusedArray[rowd][cold] = 1
        else:
            if numpyarray.item(rowd,cold) == 0:
                confusedArray[rowd][cold] = 0
            else:
                confusedArray[rowd][cold] = 2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In versions 1.4 and higher, numpy provides the [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) function.

```
>>> test = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 0])
>>> states = [0, 2]
>>> np.in1d(test, states)
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

You can use that as a mask for assignment.

```
>>> test[np.in1d(test, states)] = 1
>>> test
array([1, 1, 1, 5, 1])
```

Here are some more sophisticated uses of numpy's indexing and assignment syntax that I think will apply to your problem. Note the use of bitwise operators to replace `if`-based logic:

```
>>> numpy_array = numpy.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
>>> confused_array = numpy.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)) % 2
>>> mask = numpy.in1d(numpy_array, repeat_set).reshape(numpy_array.shape)
>>> mask
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> ~mask
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> numpy_array == 0
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> numpy_array != 0
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> confused_array[mask] = 1
>>> confused_array[~mask & (numpy_array == 0)] = 0
>>> confused_array[~mask & (numpy_array != 0)] = 2
>>> confused_array
array([[0, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 1]])
```

Another approach would be to use `numpy.where`, which creates a brand new array, using values from the second argument where `mask` is true, and values from the third argument where `mask` is false. (As with assignment, the argument can be a scalar or an array of the same shape as `mask`.) This might be a bit more efficient than the above, and it's certainly more terse:

```
>>> numpy.where(mask, 1, numpy.where(numpy_array == 0, 0, 2))
array([[0, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: Hmm, so as I understand that. If the test value is in the states list than True, which will be = 1, else it will be equal to what it was.

Is there a way to make the output
array([1,0,1,0,0])

Comment: @mkmitchell, yep, you got it. It's somewhat akin to slice assignment with normal Python lists, but a) uses numpy's more complex indexing system, and b) follows the numpy convention that assigning a scalar to a slice of an array assigns all values in the slice to that scalar value.

Comment: How about if it's a 2-D array?

Comment: @mkmitchell, it should work identically as long as the boolean mask is the same shape as the original array.

Comment: @mkmitchell, looking at the result of `in1d` when used on a 2-d array, I see that you must `reshape` it before indexing a 2-d array. In other words, if `test = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))` then `(test[np.in1d(test, states).reshape(test.shape)] == np.array([0, 2])).all() == True`.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation to my problem. I'm trying to see how I can derive what Ii'm seeking using in1d but can't seem to come up with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way of doing what you whant:

```
numpyArray = np.array([1, 8, 35, 343, 23, 3, 8]) # could be n-Dimensional array
repeatSet = np.array([3, 5, 6, 8])
mask = (numpyArray[...,None] == repeatSet[None,...]).any(axis=-1) 
print mask
>>> [False  True False False False  True  True]
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent `numpy` you could use a combination of [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to achieve this result. The first method outputs a boolean numpy array that evaluates to `True` where its vlaues are equal to an array-like specified test element (see [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)), while with the second you could create a new array that set some a value where the specified confition evaluates to `True` and another value where `False`.

### Example

I'll make an example with a random array but using the specific values you provided.

```
import numpy as np

repeatSet = ([2, 5, 6, 8])

arr = np.array([[1,5,1],
                [0,1,0],
                [0,0,0],
                [2,2,2]])

out = np.where(np.isin(arr, repeatSet), 1, 77)

> out
array([[77,  1, 77],
       [77, 77, 77],
       [77, 77, 77],
       [ 1,  1,  1]])
```